# Replace text within div by id but exclude a div within it

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to replace a text string within a `#content` div while excluding any div with a class of `.testimonialsCode`.

Replacing any `#content` div regardless of class works:

```
 $("#content:contains('I will')").each(function() {
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/I will/g, " We will ");
    $(this).html(replaced);
  });
```

Here's the problem:

Replacing any `#content` div while excluding any div with a class of `.testimnalsCode` does not work.

```
$("#content:contains('I will').not(.testimonialsCode)").each(function() {
    //                        -------------------------
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/I will/g, " We will ");
    $(this).html(replaced);
  });
```

Additional info: In the HTML structure .testimonialsCode is div and a child of #content which is the main div of the page ...

Comment: It would be helpful to have the HTML markup.

Comment: See here for a mockup: https://jsfiddle.net/qeq5k4sv/

Comment: @blablaman4000 - I just updated my answer below, it seems like you want this, right? https://jsfiddle.net/4exkjg5e/ If not, please update your answer to clarify..

Comment: Thank you @JoshCrozier your code works as i can see in the fiddle. but not when it is on my site. hmmmm. i need to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use contains and the correct operator is `:not(.testimonialsCode);` you also could use the `find()` operator.
 
here is an example.

```
$("#content").find(':not(.testimonialsCode)').each(function() {
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/I will/g, " We will ");
    $(this).html(replaced);
});
```

also, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3kbvjagv/1/) is a fiddle with your answer.

Comment: Thanks, your fiddle works but on my site it did not. I have made a new fiddle to make it more like my page. I have removed the button i also made .testimonialsCode a div and given it some paragraphs and made multiple entries, you will notice that now that they are all still replaced even the ones in the .testimonaisCode div - which is the same as what is happening on my site 

https://jsfiddle.net/f52oy9az/

Comment: @blablaman4000 Here i fixed your problem, we had to iterate through children of `#content` This fiddle should works. https://jsfiddle.net/f52oy9az/4/

Comment: Thanks - good job works in the fiddle but not on my site, I should figure it out :(

Comment: that's weird, maybe you should add a class to each `<span>`, iterate through them and if they don't have the class `testimonialsCode` (`if(!$(elem).hasClass('.testimonialsCode'))`) check for `I will` and replace it for `We will`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use jquery `.find()` to get the length of child element and if length is 0 then replace the text

```
$("#content:contain('I will')").each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.testimonialsCode').length == 0){
    var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/I will/g, " We will ");
    $(this).html(replaced);
     }
  });
```

**Note: Id should be unique through out the DOM**

Comment: Sorry it's not working. Maybe i forgot to mention that .testimonialsCode is a child of #content would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fiddle you created: the following code will work, **Note i changed the HTML**

**HTML**

```
    <div id="content"> <span>I will</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="testimonialsCode">I will</span>
  <br/>
  <span>I will</span><br>
 <span>I will</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#content span:contains('I will')").each(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('testimonialsCode')){
            var replaced = $(this).html().replace(/I will/g, " We will ");
$(this).html(replaced);

     }

 });
```

});

So just make sure that the `content` div has `span` child elements with `html` = i Will and it will work.

So the script looks for all span elements in element with id `content` which containt html of **I Will** then it loops through each found element and check if that element does not have a class called `testimonials`, then it replaces the html with your desired html.

Comment: Sorry it's not working. Maybe i forgot to mention that .testimonialsCode is a child of #content would that make a difference?